# Circle equation through 2 points

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles, conic-sections

Three points $(0,0) , (1,2) , (1,-2)$ are given. The circle through these 3 points is to be found. My textbook says the circle is $(x-1)(x-1)+(y-2)(y+2)+k(x-1)=0$. We can find $k$ by putting $x=y=0$. My issue is that this formula is not mentioned anywhere. The ones I am aware of are family of circle through 2 points and circle touching a line at $(x_1,\ y_1)$ on the line. What does the formula used above represent ?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time since they are completely independent. I've flagged this question as `Needs more focus`.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: In $Q.1$ they have used family of circles passing through through two points $A(x_1, y_1),B(x_2,y_2)$ which is given as $$(x-x_1)(x-x_2)+(y-y_1)(y-y_2)+\lambda(\text{eq. of}\ AB) $$

Comment: What is the value of $m$ in part 2?

Comment: If you dont know any formula to find out the equation of circle which passes through 3 given points then try to find a formula...and use it

Comment: Comments are not for answering questions.  This is stated very clearly in the Community Guidelines and you are reminded of this prior to writing a comment.

Comment: I have separated the quesetion @SarGe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the given 3 points, we can always take any two of them (in this case, we take P(1, 2) and Q(1, -2) for some reason!) to construct an auxiliary circle (the green one) with PQ as diameter. Its equation is:-

$C’ :(x-1)(x-1)+(y-2)(y+2)= 0$

[image]

Next, we take P and Q again to form a straight line whose equation is $L : x – 1 = 0$

L and C’ form a system of lines. Its general equation for any line that passes through the intersection points is:-
$(x-1)(x-1)+(y-2)(y+2) + k(x – 1)= 0$; for some k.

Since the required circle C (the red one) will also pass through P and Q, then C is part of the system. The equation of C is then $(x-1)(x-1)+(y-2)(y+2) + k(x – 1)= 0$ for some suitable k.

We put $x = y = 0$ to find k because $(0, 0)$ is the third point of the required circle.